# WP All Import price comparison for multiple xml data feeds

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, affiliate, wpallimport

i am currently working on a small price comparison like website with the help of WordPress and the Plugin WP All Import.

My data is provided by one Affiliate Network.

Now i don´t know how to solve the following situation:

I have like 50 Feeds (.xml). One for every partner shop on the network. Shops can have the same product in their own feed.

**How to:**

- Avoid importing duplicate items
- Items that matches the same for all feeds (for e.g the same product) i want to create only one new item on my end but list all the different external urls of all other feeds on my items page.

Maybe i need to merge the different data feeds from all shops to one before importing them?

In the end i would like to have a table similar to this example:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6tZh.png)

thanks for your help

Comment: If I were you, some of my questions would be: "What is definition of a **duplicate**? Is there some unique identifier? May be some key 10 fields? What do I want to do if I get a duplicate after importing into database?". I would put aside "format issues" for a while.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Well, there are unique identifiers like the product EAN. But not sure what to do here at all. I have a custom field table with 3 fields like "vendor, price, shop_link". Now how to manage the imports of all these different .xml feeds, check for the same product by EAN for e.g and parse the relevant information for each xml feed under the same product page for these fields?

Comment: So in general. If any of the imported fields match like the product number (EAN/PID) the items get listed on the same page and prices get compared.

Comment: I need to see your data. In absene of that, EAN sounds good to me. Create tables (one table to begin with, with EAN as primary key), parse xml messages, insert them into the table (update fields if the EAN already exists and the new xml message has any new important imformation to offer). You coud parse the xml messages using php (or better perl/python), create insert/update statements and run them against your database. I assume the feeds (xml messages) are delivered to you in the form of a file with multiple messages in them.